# Filter as you type, search for name of Div ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter, instant

Any expert out there know if there is any search jquery plugin that allows you to filter as you type in the search box and the search is based on the name of Div ID?

Also if it will instant refresh filter it will be best.

Comment: This question is not considered a good question by SE guidelines. It's off topic because "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Search for auto suggest? Data Table?

Answer (score 0):

Very broad question and not sure what you mean. The input is meant to actually search for a div itself? In any case, you could just use a few lines of jquery to search. I have included an example below.

https://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/m0pchv1j/1/

JQUERY

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
    var input = $(this).val();
    $('div').each(function(i) {
        if (input === $(this).attr('id')) {
            $(this).addClass('show');  // run your code after you find the div
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('show'); // else do whatever
        }
    });
});
```